# How to invoke shake on validation error in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a jquery code that shakes a div when clicked.

```
    $("#error").click(function() {
        $("#box-login").show('shake', 55);
        $(".header-login").show('shake', 55);
        $("#content-login .error").show('blind', 500);
        return false;
    });
```

I want to call this as a function when there is a form validation error, for example...

```
  $("#box-login").validate({
    rules: {
      username: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
      password: {// compound rule
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    url: {
      url: true
    },
    comment: {
      required: true
    }
    },
    messages: {
      comment: "Please enter a comment."
    }
  });
});
```

How do i combine these two or is there any other better method to call the shake as a function when there is some error? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing is to make your shake function its own named, reusable function:

```
function shakeIt() {
    $("#box-login").show('shake', 55);
    $(".header-login").show('shake', 55);
    $("#content-login .error").show('blind', 500);
    return false;
}
```

Then call that function from both your `click` and `invalidHandler` handlers (either directly or indirectly):

```
$("#error").click(shakeIt);

$("#box-login").validate({
    // ...rules etc...
    invalidHandler: shakeIt
});
```

Now, there I've called it directly. Note that it will be called with different arguments in the two situations; if you want to do something with those arguments, you might have separate event handlers, both of which call your `shakeIt` function:

```
$("#error").click(function(event) {
    // ...do something with `event`...
    shakeIt();
});

$("#box-login").validate({
    // ...rules etc...
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        // ...do something with `form` and/or `validator`...
        shakeIt();
    }
```

});

(Those both might also be named, reusable functions, but if they're really one-offs and if you like anonymous functions — [I don't](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) — the above would be fine.)

This is basically just a specific example of modularization, which is in general a good guideline for writing software: Make the pieces small and reusable, then string them together to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Add `invalidHandler` to your object. See [`validate()` options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).

```
 $("#box-login").validate({
    rules: {
      username: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
      password: {// compound rule
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    url: {
      url: true
    },
    comment: {
      required: true
    }
    },
    messages: {
      comment: "Please enter a comment."
    },
    invalidHandler: function() {
        $("#box-login").show('shake', 55);

    }
  });
});
```